# How can we convert Hex string to Byte, Short datatype in scala

Tags: java, scala

I am working on a small project where i required to decode the data coming as a Hexadecimal format in Scala Spark. For that I need to convert two Hexadecimal character's to signed number i.e "F0" to "-16" using Scala.(1 byte string)
And need to convert 2 byte i.e. four char hexadecimal string to signed number. But when I am trying to convert It was showing "Value out of range" Exception. Could you suggest me a simple way to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Show us the code you tried and example data.

Comment: Also consider there are already libraries to do this, you should not be writing this yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to parse it to a larger container, and then downcast:

```
val byteVal = java.lang.Long.valueOf("f0", 16).toByte      // -16
val shortVal = java.lang.Long.valueOf("fff0", 16).toShort  // -16
val intVal  = java.lang.Long.valueOf("fffffff0", 16).toInt // -16
```